# No reference to accepting answers in the FAQ

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, accept-rate

Seeing a user with a $0\%$ accept rate, I would like to point him to the relevant section of the FAQ, but it seems to be no reference to accepting answers in the FAQ.

There is some other reference I can use?
Should the FAQ be improved?

Comment: Some links are given in [this comment template](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/4945/).

Comment: For new users the system pops out a message when they upvote any answer asking them to consider accepting the answer. Also, I retagged as we try to use (faq-proposed) for an actually proposed faq item that is in the process of being hammered out, not just to discuss whether an item should be in the faq.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some links are given in [this comment template](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/4945/). I'll copy them here:

- [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/)
- [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/)
- [How does accept rate work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/)

Answer (score 5):

For what it's worth, the FAQ does talk about accepting answers under [How do I ask questions here?](https://math.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask)

> When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer.
>
> [image: accept an answer]
>
> This lets other people know that you have received a good answer to your question. Doing this is helpful because it shows other people that you’re getting value from the community. (And if you don’t do this, people will often politely ask you to go back and accept answers for more of your questions!)

Comment: Under what conditions does the site look like that screenshot?

Comment: I think maybe we see there an old format for the site.

Comment: @Tobias: The same image is used on all StackExchange sites, all of which use a slightly different design. So I think the image is not meant to look exactly like the site.